# Shrink content on smaller device

Tags: html, css

I am using the tinymce editor to allow users to create their own content. When they upload images they cause side scrolling when the output is viewed on mobile devices.

How can I shrink the content of the whole box where the images are to large?

I have tried using css media queries but as the images are set to a certain width they are still to large.

I have changed my css to this, but I am still having the same problem:

```
.coupon
{
   min-height:202px;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
 padding:2px;
 text-align:left;
 max-width:100%;
 height: auto;
```

}

Please see example.Play the quiz and select random answers for the two questions to see the overscrolling image http://www.quizzerland.com/?q=bbv.php&desc=vvv

Comment: The constraint must be place on the _images_ not on the containing `<div>` or whatever; you may want to try `.coupon img { max-width: 100%; }`.

Answer (score 4):

To have images use their natural width or the width given by the `width=` attribute on wide viewports and shrink them on narrow viewports you *can* use media queries, like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   img {
     height: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Replace `640px` in accordance with the actual design. If you cannot trust your users at all then you may want to limit the `max-width` of images at all times, not only on narrow viewports; in this case, just get rid of the media query:

```
 img {
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
```